# How to make a window remain a separate window when reassigning the parent using the Xlib function XReparentWindow()?

Tags: c, xlib

I'm trying to assign a parent to a window using the function XReparentWindow(), but after that my window becomes part of the parent window, it ends up being drawn into the parent window.

```
void setParent(Window child, Window parent) {
   Display *disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
   XReparentWindow(disp, child, parent, 0, 0);
   XCloseDisplay(disp);
}
```

Tell me please how to make a window remain a separate window when reassigning the parent using the Xlib functions?

Answer (score 0):

XSetTransientForHint(display, child, parent)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).